# Duplicate the value from the group of radio

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to duplicate the text value of the active radio buttom before other div. Radios are divided into groups. In each group is always active, only one. Therefore, a new value from each group should always be one, too. I will add a text value, but I cant to make the removal of the previous value of the group.

```
    $('.views-exposed-widget').find('.form-type-radio').on('click', function(){
        var a = $(this).closest('.form-type-radio').find('label[class="option"]').text();
        $('.views-widget-sort-by').before('<span>'+a+'</span>');
    });
```

My example: http://jsfiddle.net/e59ogp8a/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could name them (*and thus create a mapping between the radio group and the spans*) so you can find them easily

```
$('.views-exposed-widget').on('change', 'input', function () {
    var self = $(this),
        name = this.name,
        text = self.closest('.form-type-radio').find('label[class="option"]').text(),
        target = $('.views-widget-sort-by').find('[data-for="'+ name +'"]'); // find the related span

    // check if we found a related span, and if not create it
    if (target.length == 0){ 
        target = $('<span data-for="'+name+'"></span>').appendTo('.views-widget-sort-by');
    }
    // set the text of the span
    target.text( text );
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/5nutt42g/1/

---

You also had a wrong id on the the first radio (*it should be `edit-tid-1-4` and not `edit-tid-1-2`*)

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove all the prev siblings of your div element.

```
$('.views-exposed-widget').find('.form-type-radio').on('click', function(){
        var a = $(this).closest('.form-type-radio').find('label[class="option"]').text();
        $('.views-widget-sort-by').prevAll().remove();
        $('.views-widget-sort-by').before('<span>'+a+'</span>');
});
```

Comment: this removes all options, not just the current group

Answer (score 0):

You can use the group name as span's class name to clear the values of the group after group's button clicked.

Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/e59ogp8a/3/

```
$('.views-exposed-widget').find('.form-type-radio').on('click', function(){
    var a = $(this).closest('.form-type-radio').find('label[class="option"]').text();
    var groupName= $(this).find('.dls-radio').attr("name");
    console.log($('.views-widget-sort-by').prev('.'+groupName).text(''));            
    $('.views-widget-sort-by').before('<span class="'+groupName+'">'+a+'</span>');
});
```